# How to animate a code created in LaTeX in an answer or a question

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

There are many questions where many users of TeX.SE insert not only a code and an image but also a corresponding animation without using LaTeX animation packages. My question is: what is the method to animate them, rotate them, turn them, in order to better display the created output? You can help me with some examples because I have never tried this option. Thank you all for your collaboration.

Comment: The process most likely follow this post on the main site: [How to convert pstricks animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764) In short, convert a multi-page PDF into an animated GIF using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).

Comment: @Werner Very kind Werner, but if I couldn't install Image magik is there an alternative more simple and more fast? +1 for the comment.

Comment: [`standalone`](//ctan.org/pkg/standalone) may provide some functionality to match that, if I recall. Not sure whether it's dependent on ImageMagick though.

Comment: @Werner I don't know :-( that's why I asked a question about Meta. It seemed to me to be a question unrelated to TeX.SE main site.

Comment: @Sebastiano It's a valid question on meta, regarding SE web site supported animated images and tools to generate such images for the purpose of displaying here. (ImageMagick and similar tools would be offtopic on the main site). Don't worry about the usual downvote, I get one too on each of my meta posts since 3 months. I upvoted because this question thread may be an opportunity to show our users options to create and display animations on TeX.SE. And if it's done *with LaTeX*, it can collect links to LaTeX advice on the main site.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Dear moderator Stefan. Thank you so much for your comment. I thought to have installed MikTeX in an old device that uses a 32 bit Windows 7 operating system. I did not want to install anything on this old laptop that works great. Often there are a lot of free and unregistered tools but currently I don't know any of them. Ha ha ha for the downvotes that the users give me. I don't really care that much.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Generally I don't agree with other very good users who receive negative votes without any justification. I wish you and I wish all users good health especially in this very bad time for the pandemic. My best regards.

Answer (score 2):

I put a disposition of the community one site
https://www.screentogif.com/ that I have just found yesterday to record the screen, webcam and sketchboard and convert it to `.gif`.

Here there is the screenshot with the different languages.

[image]